# IntelliJ IDE with Cursive (Clojure): Custom Inspection

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, cursive, intellij-inspections

I'm using the [Cursive](https://cursive-ide.com/) plugin with IntelliJ to write Clojure.

I'd like to add two code inspections that don't come with Cursive: functions longer than 15 LOC and `defn` forms whose documentation string is (accidentally) located after the parameter vector.

I've looked through IntelliJ's [Creating Custom Inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-custom-inspections.html) page and checked out the templates used for Java code, but couldn't figure out how to look through the templates used by Cursive for the inspections that it does provide.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'd like? I'm willing to do it as manually as is necessary.